# Azure Data Factory DataFlow Filter is taking a lot of time

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF Pipleline which executes a DataFlow.
The Dataflow has Source A table which has around 1 Million Rows,
Filter which has a query to select only yesterday's records from the source table,
Alter Row settings which uses upsert,
Sink which is archival table where the records are getting upsert

This whole pipeline is taking around 2 hours or so which is not acceptable. Actually, the records being transferred / upserted are around 3000 only.

Core count is 16. Tried the partitioning with round robin and 20 partitions.
Similar archival doesn't take more than 15 minutes for another table which has around 100K records.

I thought of creating source which would select only yesterday's record but the dataset we can select only table.

Please suggest if I am missing anything to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

The table of the Data Set really doesn't matter.  Whichever activity you use to access that Data Set can be toggled to use a query instead of the whole table, so that you can pass in a value to select only yesterday's data from the database.

Or course, if you have the ability to create a stored procedure on the source, you could also do that.

When migrating really large sets of data, you'll get much better performance using a Copy activity to stage the data into an Azure Storage Blob before using another Copy activity to pull from that Blob into the source.  But, for what you're describing here, that doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: Thank you. I need to use the dataflow because it has upsert and copy doesn't have it. For using the query when i put the query the column mapping is not showing the column hence the filter is not working. Not sure what's missing here.